# Systemd + NPM start

Tags: node.js, npm, systemd

I can't seem to be able to start my express server through Systemd (ExecStart=/usr/bin/npm run start). It does work when I run the command manually. Here is the stack trace:

`` 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start',
1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
1 verbose cli   '/opt/par/p-web' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.13.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle p-web@1.0.0~prestart: p-web@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle p-web@1.0.0~start: p-web@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle p-web@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle p-web@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/opt/par/p-web/node_modules/.bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
9 verbose lifecycle p-web@1.0.0~start: CWD: /opt/par/p-web
10 silly lifecycle p-web@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'node server/server.js' ]
11 info lifecycle p-web@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
12 silly lifecycle p-web@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: -2  signal: null
13 info lifecycle p-web@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: p-web@1.0.0 start: `node server/server.js`
14 verbose stack spawn sh ENOENT
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:232:19)
14 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
14 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
15 verbose pkgid p-web@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /opt/par/p-web
17 verbose Linux 4.4.0-1072-aws
18 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "start" "--prefix" "/opt/par/p-web"
19 verbose node v10.13.0
20 verbose npm  v6.4.1
21 error file sh
22 error path sh
23 error code ELIFECYCLE
24 error errno ENOENT
25 error syscall spawn sh
26 error p-web@1.0.0 start: `node server/server.js`
26 error spawn sh ENOENT
27 error Failed at the p-web@1.0.0 start script.
27 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
28 verbose exit [ 1, true ] ``

Any ideas?

Comment: it seems your system doesn't recognize `node` under your system $PATH. Or the actual path you want node to run

Comment: I debugged this to the best of my ability, and it does not seem to be the case :(

Comment: Just run with absolute paths to both node and the server/server to see if it works, if it does you'll have isolated the issue.

Comment: It doesnt run with absolute paths

Comment: what's the output? I think if you update your question with abs paths it could be easier to debug

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing a `spawn sh ENOENT` error when trying to run an executable using `npx` through systemd. I noticed that when I ran the command under `nohup` (from the service file), it complained about not being able to find `bash`. Making sure both Node and `bash` were on my path fixed the issue, even after I took the `nohup` out of the service file.

In summary, try adding something like this to your service file's Service unit:
`Environment="PATH=/path/to/your/node/bin:/usr/bin"`